# What is the difference between Panchanana(Shiva) and Panchananda?

Tags: shiva, gods

[image]

In Bengal, there are many temples of 'Panchananda'. I do not know whether any temple of this deity exists outside of Bengal.

What is the difference between Panchanana(Shiva) and Panchananda?

Panchananda is also called Panchanana but His complexion is deep Red and the Form is fierce.

What is the scriptural source of this deity and How is He different from Panchanana (Shiva) as per the scriptures?

Comment: As you say you are not aware the temples of Panchananda outside Bengal, can you give some introduction about the deity? Something like a link?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I hv added one image.There are many videos on youtube also.